# I have 2 passports, I'd like to leave Thailand on passport A and enter another south East Asian country in passport B. Possible?

Tags: asia

I would like some advice please.

My pages in passport A are almost finished, so I would like to leave Thailand on passport A (which I arrived using) and enter another country(not any of my home countries) on passport B.

I don't see a problem if I apply for a visa in Thailand with passport B and exit with passport A and arrive in my next destination with passport B?

Please help kindly, thanks

Comment: Thailand lets you have simultaneous passports? In the U.S., they invalidate your old passport when they issue the new one...

Comment: The only issue would be if the country you are applying for a visa wants to see proof you are in Thailand legally in the passport you are applying with.

Comment: @IsaacKotlicky I suspect that the passports are not issued by Thailand.  Furthermore, "my home countries" implies that the passports are not issued by the same country.

Answer (score 2):

**Yes**, that's totally fine.  Thailand doesn't care what passport you use after leaving, and the other country won't care what passport you used before.

See also: [I have two passports/nationalities. How do I use them when I travel?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/52100/i-have-two-passports-nationalities-how-do-i-use-them-when-i-travel)

Comment: You're welcome, please click the check mark to accept if this answered your question!